# VMWare player is crashing the whole OS

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, vmware

I am using ubuntu 12.04 (with latest updates) on Lenovo Thinkpad T430. Both OS and machine are 64 bits and I got crashes when try to use vmware player to create a VM.

I have install vmware player 64 bit from the official site successfully but when I start to create a vm the whole machines restarts

Any one know the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there no message of kernel panic? Try looking at `dmesg`, especially the lines  right before the reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue. 
My setup:

- Lenovo T430s
- Ubuntu 12.04
- BIOS Ver. G7ET60WW (2.02)

Whenever I tried to open a VM using either VMware Player/WorkStation as well as Virtual box running on Ubuntu 12.04, the machine would immediately re-boot.

**What worked for me:**

In the BIOS there is a Security tab and within that there is a Virtualization section. It has two options

- Intel Virtualization Technology
- Intel VT-d Feature

Both options were disabled on my machine. I enabled both of them. Saved the new BIOS setting and re-started the machine and I was able to boot and create VM's using the above.

Try that and see if it works...